# Enable/Disable Textbox doesn't work when called from a function

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I'm using JQM 1.3 at the moment and I wanted to enable/disabled a disabled textbox using javascipt.

My script is as follow:

```
function enable(){
    $(".testText").attr("disabled", false);
}
```

and my HTML is:

```
<a onclick="enable();" data-role="button"> Enable textbox </a>
<input type="text" class="testText" disabled="disabled" />
```

When I tested this on jfiddle; it also doesn't work so I'm wondering if I'm not calling the script at the right time or I'm just doing something completely wrong somewhere.

jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ekJF/

I've also tried other ways of enabling/disabling a textbox such as:

```
$(".testText").attr("disabled", "");
$(".testText").removeAttr("disabled");
```

But nothing has worked.

Comment: it works fine!!! do you have jquery in the page???

Comment: Some dynamic content gets added to your code when you run it.You will have to do something more than just removing attribute **disabled** . Check out my solution below. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is here:
[**TextFieldEnabled**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ekJF/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="enable();" data-role="button"> Enable textbox </a><input type="text" class="testText" disabled />
```

**Jquery Used :**

```
$("a").click(function(){


try{
    $(".ui-input-text").removeClass("ui-disabled");
    $(".testText").removeClass("mobile-textinput-disabled ui-state-disabled");
    $(".testText").attr("aria-disabled",false);
$(".testText").removeAttr("disabled");
}
catch(e){ alert(e) }
})
```

Comment: Thanks qwerty. That did the trick. Made some updates for any future readers who wants to enable and disable as well and it worked. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ekJF/3/)

Comment: I just realised though; what if I have multiple disabled textboxes? This enables all of them because you select by '.ui-input-text'. I tried selecting by '.ui-input-text.testText' but that doesn't work. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ekJF/3/). Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I'm still not familiar with JQuery to understand everything.

Comment: A solution that works is to wrap each textbox in a div and select by div. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ekJF/5/). But is this the best method or is there a solution that's a lot more clean?

Comment: As some content (like class, id etc) gets added to your code dynamically which makes your element(s) disabled.So you must be familiar of what content gets added that makes your elements disabled, in order to enable your textfields. Also, selecting by **'.ui-input-text.testText'** will not work as its not a proper identifier for your element.Start practicing some Jquery. Its good and easy too.Try it once.:)

Comment: Also you can wrap a group of textfields in your div if you want them to be enabled/disabled on the link click.Its up to your need.Wrapping seems to be a good option in this case.

Comment: Practicing jquery is exactly what I'm doing now. As for the solution; I think I'll go with wrapping each input inside a div as this seems to work. I've marked your response as the answer. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote the post if it really helped!